# ¿Se puede limitar la duracion de una pregunta en python?

Tags: python

Tengo que simular un examen, pero necesito que las preguntas tengan una duracion especifica, esta es mi funcion de la pregunta.

```
def inglesEspañol():
    random.shuffle(listaNumeros)
    
    nombre = input("Ingrese su nombre: ")
    
    preguntas = random.randint(5, 10)
    
    print(f"{nombre}, su examen es de {preguntas} preguntas.".upper())
    
    for i in range(preguntas):
        randNum = random.choice(listaNumeros)
        
        print(f"{i+1}. {palabrasEspañol[randNum]}")
        
        # limitar tiempo de duracion en la respuesta
        
        respuesta = input("Ingrese su respuesta: ")
        
        if respuesta == palabrasIngles[randNum]:
            print("Correcto")
        
        else:
            print("Incorrecto")
```

Si me pueden ayudar se los agradeceria.

Comment: Te enseñaron / podes implementar multithreading?

Comment: Pregunto por que no se puede "cancelar" input, osea se puede agregar un timer que cancele el proceso en caso de timeout. Pero como tienes multiples preguntas, osea multiples inputs, tendrias que crear 1 thread por cada pregunta, para poder cancelar subprocesos, y no el proceso principal, ya que eso te tiraria el script antes de tiempo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No aclaraste que S.O estás usando, hace tiempo hice un input para simular el paso del tiempo pero funciona solo para windows, si usas otro S.O deberás adaptarlo o ver que se puede hacer, pero creo que te servirá de guía:

```
import msvcrt  #funciona en windows
import time    #para calcular el tiempo

def input_tiempo(aviso = ">>>",duracion=5):
```

defino una nueva función input,
puse un prompt y tiempo por defecto pero claro que se pueden cambiar

```
cadena=""
print (aviso)    
finaliza = time.time() + duracion
```

tomamos la hora y le sumamos el tiempo de espera

```
while time.time()< finaliza:
    if msvcrt.kbhit():
        letra= msvcrt.getche().decode('ASCII')
```

usamos las funciones de msvcrt para leer las teclas presionadas

```
if letra == "\r":   #si se presiona  ENTER
            break
        else:
            cadena+= letra
return cadena
```

por último retornamos la cadena
en tú codigo habría que agregar la función y reemplazar:

```
respuesta = input("Ingrese su respuesta: ")
```

por:

```
respuesta = input_tiempo("Ingrese su respuesta: ")
```

Espero se entienda y en todo caso te oriente a implementar tu propia función.

la función nueva completa sería:

```
import msvcrt  
import time


def input_tiempo(aviso = ">>>",duracion=5):  
    cadena=""
    print (aviso)    
    finaliza = time.time() + duracion 
    while time.time()< finaliza:
        if msvcrt.kbhit():
            letra= msvcrt.getche().decode('ASCII')  
            if letra == "\r":   #si se presiona  ENTER
                break
            else:
                cadena+= letra
    return cadena
```

Desconozco como funcionará en idles distintos al shell de python.

Comment: Muchas gracias, me sirve demasiado.